# c - can't get multiple strings with scanf()

Tags: c, string, scanf

I've been struggling to get two lines seperated with space and my scanf() is not working properly
This is the code

```
char *str1, *str2;
while(1) {
    printf("Enter string:\n");
    scanf(" %s", str1);
    printf("Then;");
    scanf(" %s", str2);
    if(strcmp(str1, "exit") == 0){break;}
    printf("Output:\n %s %s\n", str1, str2);
}
```

But my output seems like this:

```
Enter string:
ok 
Then;hello
Output:
ok (null)
Enter string:
Then;
```

What would cause this problem? And it prints first output as the loop turns second time.

```
Enter string:
ok 
Then;hello
Output:
ok (null)
Enter string:
Then;well
Output:
hello (null)
Enter string:
Then;no
Output:
well (null)
Enter string:
```

Comment: you never initialized `str1` and `str2`.

Comment: Make them arrays rather than pointers. `char str1[100], str2[100];`

Comment: alright malloc worked thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"%s"` in `scanf(" %s", str1);` expects  `str1` to point to valid memory to store a *string*.    `str1` in not initialized - it does not point to valid memory.

Instead provide valid memory and limit input width.

```
char str[100];
scanf("%99s", str1);
```

The array `str` is converted to a pointer to the beginning of the array when passed to `scanf("%99s", str1);`

The leading space in `" %s"` is not needed as `"%s"` itself consumes leading white-space,
just like `" "`.